# Activation of the app for the Windows.Launch contract failed: Invalid value for registry

Tags: c#, deployment, uwp, windows-10, registry

I have a UWP application, written in C#, which gets deployed onto thousands of Windows 10 devices. Once an update is available, the app gets redeployed onto these devices. The deployment is done via PowerShell (side load). Under rare circumstances, roughly one in a thousand, the app cannot be started and leaves no log nor error message anywhere except for an entry in the event log:

[image]

> Activation of the app {AppName}_{AppKey}!App for the Windows.Launch
>   contract failed with error: Invalid value for registry.

The issue is discussed by Microsoft Support for Windows 8: 
[Apps fail to start if default registry or file permissions modified](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2798317/win8-app-modern-apps-fail-to-start-if-default-registry-or-file-permiss). The suggested solutions don't work. There's a similar issue reported [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7fb34424-655f-4ff2-bd9b-d52fe12ff61f/windowslaunch-contract-failed-with-error-the-remote-procedure-call-failed?forum=winappswithcsharp), but that doesn't help either.

Observed circumstances:

- If an installation fails, it fails. Whether it gets re-installed or not under the same or a different user account doesn't matter. It is independent which previous version was installed and whether it is uninstalled first or not.
- Repackaging the exact same software and deploying it again helps, but may fail on another device.
- Some devices appear to be immune, some have that issue only once, some have that issue from time to time. There's no obvious pattern visible.

I am stranded with this one as there is near no help online. Any whatsoever little hint, help, guess, or master answer would be appreciated.